# How to move Multi Column List line items to another list box along with multi column value excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Try to move listbox items with the below code.
its working, but its coming only one column value, there are total 6 columns in the list box

```
 Private Sub ListBoxProSlt_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
 Dim ProList As String
    ProList = ListBoxProSlt.List(ListBoxProSlt.ListIndex)
    ListBoxProRec.AddItem ProList

End Sub
```

Any suggestion to move all columns value to next list box!!

Answer (score 0):

using  loop you can add more item from one list  to another
here

```
 Private Sub ListBoxProSlt_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
 Dim ProList As String
 count=0
columnIndex = 0

For rowIndex  = 0 To ListBoxProSit.ListCount - 1
  count = count + ListBox1.List(rowIndex , columnIndex )
Next
 i=0
 do until i > count  
    ProList = ListBoxProSlt.List(i)
    ListBoxProRec.AddItem ProList
 i=i+1
loop

End Sub
```

i hope it solve's your problem

Comment: may i know what it  does

Comment: after changing the code , list box items not even moving from one to another, previously on double click its used to move single column!!

Comment: wait i am looking for another solution ..thank you FYI

Comment: its coming error in this line,                          count=ListBoxProSlt.Items.Count after ListBoxProSlt . items option is not coming in VBA